# Can I construct a ClassManifest for a parameterized type without having manifests for the type parameters?

Tags: scala

ClassManifest[T] are used in Scala primarily to create Array[T]s.

Im interested in the case where the array type T is not a primitive but some class that takes type constructors, ie a subtype of AnyRef. Can I then construct a ClassManifest for the parameterized type without having manifests for it's type parameters?

```
class Foo[A]

def getManifestFor[A]: ClassManifest[Foo[A]] = ???
```

Since Foo is non-primitive, it seems that the JVM array storage will be an array of references, whose size/memory layout is unaffected by the erased type parameters (eg A above).  So it seems possible in theory, but I don't know how to write it in Scala.

Comment: Some experimentation has answered my question:  
`def manifestFor[A]: ClassManifest[Foo[A]] = implicitly[ClassManifest[Foo[A]]]`.

`implicitly` searches for an implicit ClassManifest[Foo[A]]. I guess the compiler can provide one for the reasons I mentioned above.

Now, in retrospect this seems obvious. I got originally confused because in my app I was careless with types, and used Manifest[T], not ClassManifest[T]. 

Manifest[T] implies more accuracy; all the parts of type T must be known. Ie this is a compile error:   

`def manifestFor[A]: Manifest[Foo[A]] = implicitly[Manifest[Foo[A]]]`

Comment: why the implicitly solution would not be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is right and as you have underlined, a ClassManifest is "lighter" than a Manifest and you can build it from the type constructor.

```
scala> class Foo[A] 
defined class Foo

scala>  object test { def getManifestFor[A] = implicitly[ClassManifest[Foo[A]]] } 
defined module test

scala>  test.getManifestFor[Foo[Int]]
res2: ClassManifest[Foo[Foo[Int]]] = Foo[<?>]

scala>  :javap -p test
Compiled from "<console>"
public final class test$ extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public static final test$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public scala.reflect.ClassManifest getManifestFor();
    public test$();
}
```